# Maybe bails out of fold

Tags: haskell

Why does computing the following expression terminate?

```
foldr (\x t -> if x > 5 then Just x else t) Nothing $ [1..]
```

Is there anything special about `Maybe` (or one of the type classes it implements) that causes evaluation to stop after the lambda returns a `Just`?

Answer (score 5):

`Maybe` ,`Just`, and `Nothing` play no active role here. What we see is just laziness at work. Indeed, for any (total) function `f` and value `a`, this would also terminate:

```
foldr (\x t -> if x > 5 then f x else t) a $ [1..]
```

This is perfectly equivalent to the plain recursion

```
foo [] = a
foo (x:xs) = if x > 5 then f x else foo xs
```

when called as `foo [1..]`. Eventually, `x` becomes `6`, `f 6` is returned, and no more recursive calls are made.

Comment: The key is that the function given to `foldr` is non-strict in its second argument.